# Microsoft cognitive API token doesn't work

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use the Microsoft cognitive API for text analysis using the recommended `curl` method from [their documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/text-analytics-api):

```
curl -v -X POST "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment" -H "Content-Type: application/jscp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {bc94cba9b84748ebb2f2b79a28ee3450}" --data-ascii "{I had a wonderful experience! The rooms were wonderful and the staff were helpful.}"
```

But I get back:

```
{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription." }
```

I also tried removing the `{}` surrounding token and text to be analyzed. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

*Note: yes I realize the security issue with showing key but I have re-generated thanks.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues with your request:

- `Content-Type` header should be `application/json`.  This is likely a copy-paste error.
- `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` header value must be the API *without* the curly braces.  This is the cause for your 401 error.
- The body must be JSON of a particular format.  You can find the schema [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c9).

Here's the rewritten request:

```
curl -v "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $OXFORD_TEXT_KEY" --data-ascii '{"documents":[{"language":"en","id":"1234","text":"I had a wonderful experience! The rooms were wonderful and the staff were helpful."}]}'
```

Which should result in:

```
{"documents":[{"score":0.9750894,"id":"1234"}],"errors":[]}
```